# declarar lista list<> como atributo de objeto c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
namespace MODELO{
    [Table("Check_lists_PVR")]
    public class Check_lists_PVR{
        [Key]
        private Int64 NroCL { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public string Turno { get; set; }
        public string PVR { get; set; }
        public string Operador { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Mi intención es agregarle 3 listas como atributos. El objeto en si es un check list, cada item del mismo se divide en "item, estado y observacion", y el check list se compone de 16 items. mi idea es hacer una lista para "items" otra para "estados" y una ultima parra "observaciones" pero todos mis intentos por crear una lista arrojan error. ayuda porfavor

Comment: Si agregaras a tu pregunta el error que te lanza podria ayudarte.

Comment: Es que son varios. Por ejemplo si escribo "public list <>  observacion { get; set; }" el error es: uso inesperado de un nombre generico sin enlazar.

Comment: Si escribo "publi list <observaciones> Observaciones {get; set;} el error es: el nombre del tipo o del espacio 'observaciones' no se encontro (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

Comment: si haces public list<> ... te da error porque entre <> tienes que poner el tipo de dato que va a almacenar la lista. Si pones public list <observaciones> Observaciones y te da el error que has dicho, lo que te falta es hacer un import de la clase observaciones.

Comment: osea que las observaciones deberia haccerlas como objetos aparte?

Comment: observaciones debería ser un objeto. Si quieres hacer un listado de enteros es list<int> ... si lo quieres de string es list<string>... si lo quieres de objeto personas es list<Persona>.... Lo que pones entre<> es el tipo que va a almacenar la lista. si quieres que almacene observaciones tienes que crear el objeto observaciones con sus atributos y listo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si las observaciones son un tipo simple como string la declaración de la lista seria:

```
public List<string> Observaciones  { get; set; }
```

Por otra parte si observaciones es un tipo compuesto debes crearte una clase Observaciones que la implemente y realizar una lista de objetos de esa clase observaciones:

```
public class Observaciones
{
     // Contenido de la clase
}
```

y la declaración de la lista seria:

```
 public List<Observaciones> Observacioneses { get; set; }
```

Un saludo